# aws Lambda created ENI not deleting while deletion of stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

CloudFormation creates Lambda function. When the function is executed an ENI is provisioned automatically by lambda. The ENI seems to be left in existence after function execution for to speed up subsequent function execution. CloudFormation deletes the lambda function. The`EN` remains behind. When attempting to delete the `VPC CloudFormation stack`, stack deletion fails as the ENI is using a `security group and subnet`.

in my `lambda role` the `delete permission` are there.

> "Effect": "Allow", "Action": [ "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface", "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface", "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces" ], "Resource": "*"

I am using custom resource to run the lambda from CloudFormation template, so lambda will be called both stack creation and deletion. The ENI will be used in creation of stack and deletion of stack. Now how to handle the eni deletion?

Comment: For extra clarity please provide a minimal CloudFormation template that reproduces your issue.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is a known issue when using Lambda Functions in a VPC, as documented in [Configuring a Lambda Function to Access Resources in an Amazon VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html#vpc-configuring):

> There is a delay between the time your Lambda function executes and ENI deletion. If you do delete the role immediately after function execution, you are responsible for deleting the ENIs.

The documentation doesn't specify exactly how long this "delay" will be, but a [forum post by Richard@AWS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=734756#734756) suggests it can last up to **6 hours**(!). (In my observations using AWS CloudTrail, the delay between Lambda execution and ENI deletion was around **one hour**.)

Until AWS addresses this issue further, you can workaround the issue by detaching and deleting the leftover ENIs in between deleting the Lambda function and deleting the associated Security Group(s) and Subnet(s). This is how [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) currently [handles](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/8033) this [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/5767) in its framework.

You can do this manually by separating the VPC/Subnet/SG layer and the Lambda-function layer into two different CloudFormation Stacks, or you can automate it by implementing a Custom Resource to delete the ENIs using the AWS SDK.

Here's a complete working example that creates a VPC-Lambda Custom Resource, cleaning up its ENIs when deleted using the `VPCDestroyENI` Custom Resource:

[image: Launch Stack]

```yaml
Description: Creates a VPC-Lambda Custom Resource, cleaning up ENIs when deleted.
Parameters:
  VPCId:
    Description: VPC Id
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
  SubnetId:
    Description: Private Subnet Id
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
Resources:
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Lambda VPC security group
      VpcId: !Ref VPCId
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal: {Service: [lambda.amazonaws.com]}
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: "/"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: DetachNetworkInterface
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: 2012-10-17
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: ['ec2:DetachNetworkInterface']
            Resource: '*'
  AppendTest:
    Type: Custom::Split
    DependsOn: VPCDestroyENI
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt AppendItemToListFunction.Arn
      List: [1, 2, 3]
      AppendedItem: 4
  AppendItemToListFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          var response = require('cfn-response');
          exports.handler = function(event, context) {
             var responseData = {Value: event.ResourceProperties.List};
             responseData.Value.push(event.ResourceProperties.AppendedItem);
             response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, responseData);
          };
      Timeout: 30
      Runtime: nodejs4.3
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds: [!Ref SecurityGroup]
        SubnetIds: [!Ref SubnetId]
  VPCDestroyENIFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          var response = require('cfn-response');
          var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
          exports.handler = function(event, context) {
            console.log("REQUEST RECEIVED:\n", JSON.stringify(event));
            if (event.RequestType != 'Delete') {
              response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, {});
              return;
            }
            var ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
            var params = {
              Filters: [
                {
                  Name: 'group-id',
                  Values: event.ResourceProperties.SecurityGroups
                },
                {
                  Name: 'description',
                  Values: ['AWS Lambda VPC ENI: *']
                }
              ]
            };
            console.log("Deleting attachments!");
            // Detach all network-interface attachments
            ec2.describeNetworkInterfaces(params).promise().then(function(data) {
              console.log("Got Interfaces:\n", JSON.stringify(data));
              return Promise.all(data.NetworkInterfaces.map(function(networkInterface) {
                var networkInterfaceId = networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceId;
                var attachmentId = networkInterface.Attachment.AttachmentId;
                return ec2.detachNetworkInterface({AttachmentId: attachmentId}).promise().then(function(data) {
                  return ec2.waitFor('networkInterfaceAvailable', {NetworkInterfaceIds: [networkInterfaceId]}).promise();
                }).then(function(data) {
                  console.log("Detached Interface, deleting:\n", networkInterfaceId);
                  return ec2.deleteNetworkInterface({NetworkInterfaceId: networkInterfaceId}).promise();
                });
              }));
            }).then(function(data) {
              console.log("Success!");
              response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, {});
            }).catch(function(err) {
              console.log("Failure:\n", JSON.stringify(err));
              response.send(event, context, response.FAILED, {});
            });
          };
      Timeout: 300
      Runtime: nodejs4.3
  VPCDestroyENI:
    Type: Custom::VPCDestroyENI
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt VPCDestroyENIFunction.Arn
      SecurityGroups: [!Ref SecurityGroup]
Outputs:
  Output:
    Description: output
    Value: !Join [",", !GetAtt AppendTest.Value]
```

<sub>Note: To create the VPC and Private Subnet required in the above example, you can use the [AWS Quick Start](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/) [Amazon VPC Architecture](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/vpc/) [template](https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/aws/vpc/latest/templates/aws-vpc.template).</sub>

Comment: i am using custom resource to run the lambda from CFT, so lambda will be called both stack creation and deletion. The ENI will be used in creation of stack and deletion of stack. Now how to handle the eni deletion?

Comment: Updated my answer based on this additional context.

Comment: i created a non vpc lambda and added settimeout, but we cannot wait more than five minutes why because lambda will tim out after 5 minutes. i gave set time out 4 min and calling non vpc lambda from custom resource as delay between function execution and vpc deletion. still issue is coming. and one more point i need to add here i am deploying lambda from CFT and i am running same lambda from custom resource. In deletion it will run first after that it will delete the lambda. is this creating eni problem.

Comment: It seems that the amount of time needed for the delay is up to 6 hours(!), so a 5-minute timeout will not be sufficient. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Looks like the best approach is to use an extra Custom Resource to detach+delete the leftover ENIs, rather than waiting hours for them to detach on their own. I've added a complete working example with a Custom Resource implementation demonstrating the fix.

Comment: Thank you very much, as of now using the above code working fine. only one change in lambda code  Filters: [
                {
                  Name: 'group-id',
                  Values: [event.ResourceProperties.SecurityGroups]
                }   passing values as array other wise lambda throwing error

Comment: is it possible to create ENI through CFT and assign to the lambda and dlete the ENI from CFT in deletion process.

Comment: No, unfortunately the [Lambda API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Reference.html) does not provide any access to the network interfaces- you provide a [VpcConfig](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_VpcConfig.html) object (SecurityGroupIds and SubnetIds) and the service manages the ENI creation on its own, no further configuration is currently possible.

Comment: Any progress here? Is it still neccessary to do this? I have some problems deleting the ENIs. Sometimes it is working, sometimes not. ENIs wont be detached or deleted. I think, this is still an error...

Comment: @Stefan the AWS documentation I quoted in my answer hasn't changed, so I would assume the ENI-management behavior hasn't changed either.

Comment: What would be the effect of enabling Hyperplane networking for Lambdas in a VPC (See [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/)) on this please?