# Deleting stack does not delete ENI created by ECS- stack deletion goes forever

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

AWS ECS created ENI not deleting while deletion of stack.
I am using ECS that creates its own ENI. When deleting the stack the deletion takes forever. When going to cloudformation and checking the stack I see a security group cannot be deleted. Also in the security group, I see that a bunch of ENI is hanging there.
Please help!

Comment: Is the SG used by something else?

Comment: It is a company-wide security group. I found similar issues [aws Lambda created ENI not deleting while deletion of stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299662/aws-lambda-created-eni-not-deleting-while-deletion-of-stack) that ENI was created by Lambda, but our ENI is created by ECS